SHT_DYNAMIC->SHT_DYNSYM?
The ELF file spec at https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/gabi4+/ch4.sheader.html#sh_link says that for sections of type SHT_DYNAMIC, the sh_link in the section header should contain the index of the associated string table. String table, not symbol table.
Yet here I am looking at a binary where sh_link points to a section of type SHT_DYNSYM. Does that make sense from the loader logic standpoint? DYNSYM is not a string table. The DYNSYM section links to a DYNSTR one, so I guess an indirect link to a strtable can be drawn.
The file is an OAT one for ARM/Android, superficially ELF.
